# How to connect to AWS Client VPN from ubuntu box?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, vpn

I have used this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html) to create aws vpn client endpoint. Now i want connect to this vpn endpoint from my ubuntu box.

For that i have downloaded the client certificates and using this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html.en) for connecting to vpn using TLS authentication method.

But when i tried to connect to VPN from my Network Manager, I'm getting timed out.

Note: I have already open all UDP traffic for my system.

Below is the output of syslog. Please let me know what is going wrong.

```
~$ org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2480]: message repeated 3 times: [ ** (process:17599): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted]
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886812.2980] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63" name="Client-VPC" pid=2697 uid=1001 result="success"
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886812.3117] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 9091
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886812.3297] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[9094] started
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886812.3394] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886812.3394] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: NOTE: chroot will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET] **.**.**.**:1194
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <warn>  [1552886872.9227] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: libnm-Message: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[9094]: send SIGTERM
~$ nm-openvpn[9094]: SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <warn>  [1552886872.9266] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: nm-openvpn-Message: openvpn[9094] exited with success
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886872.9273] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
~$ NetworkManager[30373]: <info>  [1552886872.9277] vpn-connection[0x2501430,705a6afa-a5b0-420b-858e-4feae6244a63,"Client-VPC",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
~$ org.freedesktop.Notifications[2480]: ** (notify-osd:2694): WARNING **: dnd_is_idle_inhibited(): got error "The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files"
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am assuming you followed the entire page you linked. What is your IP Address range on your personal network, most routers are 192.168.0.0 some are 10.0.0.0, what is the range of your subnet that you are connecting too. If they are the same you will not be able to connect to that network.

Comment: You mentioned you provided UDP access, you VPN client should have all traffic UDP and TCP to the VPN gateway

Comment: The log file is complaining about certificates. Is you open vpn client correct. You can place the certificates in the client configuration file or as files in the config folder. See examples here: https://wiki.teltonika.lt/view/OpenVPN_configuration_examples

Comment: The CIDR block used is different from that of the subnet. I was able to connect to the VPN based on your link shared. But i'm still unable to ssh into the ec2 machines using there private IP. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: First test, would be to open ssh to 0.0.0.0 VPN in and see if it works. If it does then it is an IP issue on the security group of the ec2 instance, If it does not then it is either a routing issue from the VPN to the EC2 instance, or the port is blocked on the VPN.

Comment: I have opened ssh port to ```0.0.0.0/0```. But even then i'm not able to connect to the instance using private IP. While with public IP i'm able to connect in both cases, i.e with VPN and without VPN.

Comment: And also, whenever i tried to connect to any of the Ec2 box or even ping it, the connection gets terminated in the Client VPN Endpoint ```Connections``` portal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190289/discussion-between-vinay-wadagavi-and-jason).

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-vpn-admin-guide.pdf)

Sometimes there are extra steps missing in the web docs like:

> After you create the client vpn endpoint, the console displays the DNS name, for example, "
>   cvpn-endpoint-0102bc4c2e49f1e44.prod.clientvpn.us-west-2.amazonaws.com". When you
>   need to specify the DNS name, you must specify a random string in front of the displayed
>   name so that the format is “[random string].displayed DNS name, for example, “asdfa.cvpnendpoint-0102bc4c2e49f1e44.prod.clientvpn.us-west-2.amazonaws.com".